# How to sort Plotly bar chart in descending order

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, plotly, data-visualization

I have created a basic bar chart in plotly that I would like to sort by descending order.
[image]

I couldn't find an easy way to specify this in the plotly syntax, so I tried modifying the dataframe with Pandas. This also hasn't worked.

My code is below:

```
import plotly.plotly as py
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import pandas as pd


df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/Documents/Python/CKANMay.csv')
sd = df.nlargest(3,'Views')
fd = sd.sort_values(by='Views', ascending = False)


my_data = [go.Bar( x = fd.Views, y = fd.Publisher, orientation = 'h')]
my_layout = ({"title": "Most popular publishers",
                       "yaxis": {"title":"Publisher"},
                       "xaxis": {"title":"Views"},
                       "showlegend": False})

fig = go.Figure(data = my_data, layout = my_layout)

py.iplot(fig)
```

I would like to invert the bar chart, so that the column with the greatest value is on the top. Appreciative for any assistance.

Comment: Can you try 'ascending=True`? Plotly just plots the values in the same order as the come.

Comment: Hah, yep that did it. I assumed True was the default value, so didn't even try that.

Answer (score 22):

Add this to update your figure:

```
fig.update_layout(barmode='stack', xaxis={'categoryorder':'total descending'})
```

Answer (score 10):

Update your layout with this:

```
fig.update_layout(yaxis=dict(autorange="reversed"))
```

source [here](https://community.plotly.com/t/flipping-horizontal-bar-chart-to-descending-order/15456)

Example:

[image]